# IF (AND () function does not work as it should be

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

When I write the following simplified command in a cell,

```
=IF(AND(C6="A";D6="30");D2;0)
```

it does not appear the value of the cell **D2** but zero, depsite the fact that the 2 assuptions of IF(AND) are fulfilled!

Do you have any idea about what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value type in D6 might be a number and you might be comparing it with a text value, try removing the quotes around the number 30. This might solve your problem. (I don't have excel around).